# How select between multiple programs with same name for linux shell?

Tags: command-line, default-programs, paths

I've already installed an old version of mysql server into my linux system using repository in `/usr/bin` path. Recently I upgraded it to latest version using linux binary package (with no installer) & for some reasons I didn't remove old version just now, but don't use it anymore.
The problem is that when I want to run files such as `mysqldump` or `mysql_upgrade` they are executing from old path:

```
$> which mysqldump
   /usr/bin/mysqldump
```

the question is that how can i change it to my new installation in `/usr/local/mysql/bin` path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `/usr/local/mysql/bin/` to your `$PATH` environment variable by adding the following line at the bottom of your Bash configuration file (`~/.bashrc`):

```
PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
```

I assume here that you only want this for your own user account, if you want to change this system-wide, let me know in the comments. I also assume you're using Bash as your shell. Other shells have similar solutions.

**EDIT:** In order to enable this change for all users (who have Bash as their login shell), add the `PATH=` line to the file `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: I use bash, please let me know how to do this for all users

Comment: I just updated my answer as you requested.